# No PDF output after updating Ghostscript to version 9.16

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, output, ghostscript

I use TeXnicCenter 2.02 64bit, MikTeX 2.9 64bit and I produce pdf files with gswin64c.exe. My command line in TeXnicCenter is

```
-sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="%bm.pdf" -c save pop -f "%bm.ps"
```

Everything works well with version 9.07 of Ghostscript but after update to version 9.16 I am getting following error:

```
Error: /undefinedfilename in ... (here is the path to my file)

Operand stack:

Execution stack:

%interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval--  --nostringval-- --nostringval--  false 1 %stopped_push

Dictionary stack:

--dict:1195/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:78/200(L)--

Current allocation mode is local

Last OS error: No such file or directory

GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Out of curiosity, why do you need postscript?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I uninstalled all previous versions of Ghostscript so now I have only the latest one 9.16 and after restarting the computer my Output profile latex->ps->pdf works fine.

Comment: The problem appeared again! And after some testing I found what causes it. I am from the Czech republic and some file paths has special characters (like š, ě, á, …). When my file path has these special letters, Ghostscript 9.16 crashes. When it is without them, it works fine!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue fixed by reinstalling the software.